# How to stream Chart Images as FileResult from MVC Controllers update via jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts

I am experimenting with Nic's method of streaming images as FileResult from controllers. [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MvcChartControlFileResult.aspx).

I thought I take it a step further and have an image get updated via jQuery.
**I have tried all sorts of ways but can't get the image to show. In this current state I am seeing all the characters of the PNG, I think it is sending the binary data.**
Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

**Partial View**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<img src="/Home/GetHistoryChart" alt="My Chart" id="imgHistoryChart" />
```

**Page**

```
<input id="begindate" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;" />
<input id="enddate" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;"  />
<input type="submit" value="Refresh" id="refreshHistory" />
<div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="theImageHistory">
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Charts/HistoryImg.ascx"); %></div>
<%--Gets the partial view shown above--%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#refreshHistory").click(function() {
        var fromDate = $("#begindate").val();
        var toDate = $("#enddate").val();
        RefreshImage(fromDate, toDate);
    });
});
function RefreshImage(from, to) {
 $('div#theImageHistory').load('/Home/GetHistoryChart', { fromDate: '8/1/2009', toDate : '8/24/2009' },
    function(html) {
        //$('div#theImageHistory')[0].value = html;
        alert('Do I get here');

    });
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public FileResult GetHistoryChart(string? fromDate, string? toDate)
{
 //  code...
 System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Chart1.SaveImage(imageStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return new FileResult("Yo.png", "image/png", imageStream.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery load function expects to get HTML from the server, but you are calling into an action which returns a binary stream, so the binary stream is converted to text before it is displayed as HTML.

You could rewrite RefreshImage as simply as this:

```
function RefreshImage(from, to) {
    $('imgHistoryChart')[0].src = '/Home/GetHistoryChart?' +
                                  'fromDate=' + escape(from) + 
                                  '&toDate=' + escape(to);
}
```

All you really need to do is update the SRC for the image element. I would also disable HTTP caching for the action so that the browser doesn't show a cached image where the URL is the same (unless that's what you want).